# python salt - Comment: No states found for this minion

Tags: python, salt-stack

wowee....trying to lean salt...my lord...trying to follow there online tutorial.

I am running the master and minion on localhost

Here is my error

```
sudo salt-call state.highstate -l debug
[DEBUG   ] Loaded upstart as virtual service
[DEBUG   ] Loaded useradd as virtual user
[DEBUG   ] Loaded dpkg as virtual lowpkg
[DEBUG   ] Loaded debconfmod as virtual debconf
[DEBUG   ] Loaded cmdmod as virtual cmd
[DEBUG   ] Loaded virtualenv_mod as virtual virtualenv
[DEBUG   ] Loaded djangomod as virtual django
[DEBUG   ] Loaded saltmod as virtual salt
[DEBUG   ] Loaded zcbuildout as virtual buildout
[DEBUG   ] Loaded debconfmod as virtual debconf
[DEBUG   ] Loaded virtualenv_mod as virtual virtualenv
[DEBUG   ] MinionEvent PUB socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_1d41c853af58d3a7ae54990ce29417d8_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MinionEvent PULL socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_1d41c853af58d3a7ae54990ce29417d8_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Fetching file from saltenv 'base', ** attempting ** 'salt://ssh.sls'
[INFO    ] Fetching file from saltenv 'base', ** skipped ** latest already in cache 'salt://ssh/init.sls'
[DEBUG   ] Loaded no_out as virtual quiet
[DEBUG   ] Loaded json_out as virtual json
[DEBUG   ] Loaded yaml_out as virtual yaml
[DEBUG   ] Loaded pprint_out as virtual pprint
local:
----------
          ID: states
    Function: no.None
      Result: False
     Comment: No states found for this minion
     Changes:   

Summary
------------
Succeeded: 0
Failed:    1
------------
Total:     1
```

Here is my top.sls

```
base:
  '*':
    - ssh
```

here is my ssh/init.sls

```
openssh-client:
  pkg.installed

/etc/ssh/ssh_config:
  file.managed:
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
    - source: salt://ssh/ssh_config
    - require:
      - pkg: openssh-client
```

So?  What is the deal?

Comment: Have you modified the `file_roots` config option in your /etc/salt/master?

Comment: Also, does  /srv/salt/ssh.sls  exist?

Comment: Yes..I changed the location of file_root in /etc/salt/master